# Why does Flask still print log info to console even without adding stream handler?

Tags: python, flask, logging

I have a logger defined as in logger.py:

```
def my_logger(module_name):

    logger = logging.getLogger(module_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # stream handler
    

    # debug handler
    f1_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(abspath, "logs/debug.log"))
    f1_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    f1_handler.setFormatter(format)

    # warning handler
    f3_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(abspath, "logs/warning.log"))
    f3_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    f3_handler.setFormatter(format)

    # error handler
    f4_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(abspath, "logs/error.log"))
    f4_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    f4_handler.setFormatter(format)

    # Add handlers to the logger
    
    logger.addHandler(f1_handler)
    logger.addHandler(f3_handler)
    logger.addHandler(f4_handler)

    return logger
```

Then in my test.py, I can test the logger as test.py:

```
from kg import logger
logger = logger.my_logger(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   logger.info('Start main ...')
```

This works as expected, the logger message only goes to debug.log file under my logs/debug.log, meaning that it doesn't print the message to console.

However, if I test it in a Flask application, and in browser I sent a request, it always print the log message to console as well, in addition to the log file.

My flask api in flask_test.py:

```
from search import keyword_match
@api.route('/match', methods=['GET'])
def match():
    text, parameters = _parse_parameters()
    
    json_result = keyword_match(text, **parameters)
    return json_result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #api.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='5000')
    logger.info('Test log in Flask api!')
    from waitress import serve
    serve(api, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

The logger here in the 'main' still works as expected, it doesn't print out to console, since no stream handler is configured in my logger. However, there is a logger message in search.py, which defines the keyword_match function:

```
from kg import logger
logger = logger.my_logger(__name__)

   def keyword_match(keyword, **args):
       logger.info('keyword: {}'.format(keyword))
       ...
```

It is in this file, it always prints out the log info onto console even if there is no stream handler in my own logger definition. It seems Flask stream handler is always turned on and how to turn it off? I tried this in my flask_test.py, but it didn't helper:

```
logger = logger.my_logger(__name__)

app = Flask(__name__)
from flask.logging import default_handler
app.logger.removeHandler(default_handler)
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving/removing this line of code: `logger = logger.my_logger(__name__)` to after you remove the default handler?

From my understanding, flask has a default understanding of what the logger object is. But having that line of code before you reference `app.logger` means that the meaning of `logger` has been changed.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
from flask.logging import default_handler
app.logger.removeHandler(default_handler)
logger = logger.my_logger(__name__)
```